# Regular set definition

Tags: regular-expressions

I came across the following regular sets definition:

> Let Σ be a finite alphabet. Regular sets over Σ are defined recursively as
>   follows:
>
> 1. ∅ (i. e. an empty set) is a regular set over Σ,
> 2. {ε} is a regular set over Σ,
> 3. {a} is a regular set over Σ for all a ∈ Σ,
> 4. if P and Q are the regular sets over Σ, then also
>      
>    (a) P ∪ Q,
>      
>    (b) P.Q,
>      
>    (c) P ∗
>      
>    are the regular sets over Σ.
> 5. Nothing else is a regular set.

I cannot understand why is this definition complete. What I gather from points 4. and 5. is that 
 Q.P and Q * are not a regular set. Why doesn't 4. look like this?

> 4. if P and Q are the regular sets over Σ, then also
>      
>    (a) P ∪ Q,
>      
>    (b) P.Q, Q.P
>      
>    (c) P ∗, Q *
>      
>    are the regular sets over Σ.

Comment: That would be redundant.

Comment: I must be missing something. If P = {abc} and Q = {def}, how can I get Q.P {defabc} using P.Q and nothing else?

Comment: How about taking $Q=\{abc\}$, $P=\{def\}$?

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry if this seems dumb, my math is mostly self-thought. Is there a way to define the rules the way I interpreted it? Where Q.P and Q * would be excluded?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude $P.Q$ and $P^*$?

Comment: No particular reason. I'm just trying to grasp how these formal definitions work.

Comment: What you find confusing is probably due to grammar issues: it shouldn't be "the" regular sets, but "some", or better : no article at all. As "if P and Q **are regular sets** then ... **are also regular sets** over Σ."